# missing column 'CONTEXTS' after Liquibase migration to version 3.4.0 from 2.0.4

Tags: liquibase

I try to migrate Liquibase from old version 2.0.5 to 3.4.0. The first thing I tried was the status command, what resulted in a problem reading the table 'databasechangelog':

> Error executing SQL SELECT
>   FILENAME,AUTHOR,ID,MD5SUM,DATEEXECUTED,ORDEREXECUTED,EXECTYPE,DESCRIPTION,COMMENTS,TAG,LIQUIBASE,LABELS,CONTEXTS
>   FROM IDENTSERVICE.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC,
>   ORDEREXECUTED ASC: ORA-00904: "CONTEXTS"

I seems the are two new columns in the table: LABELS and CONTEXTS
The Lquibase website told it is just a drop-in replacement.

So my question: Do I need to go fist to version 3.0.0, or how do I get the new columns? Manual manipulation is not a option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not running the status command but the update command that worked well.
Be careful, you can not go back to the old version of Liquibase. The old version thows checksum errors.

Comment: Liquibase 3.4.1 fixes the issue so you can run status before running update now.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [´StandardChangeLogHistoryService´](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java) class.

Search for `hasContexts` e.g. There is code that checks if those columns are there. 
So if the test for the column `CONTEXTS` fails there should be a log line that says:

`"Adding missing databasechangelog.contexts column"`.

You can check you log for this.

So, yes it is supposed to be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: The log entry you mentioned I  can not find. I set the log level to debug with the option _--logLevel=debug_
What I understand liquibase first connects to the DB then it loads the _dbchangelog-2.0.xsd_. Right after that it queries the table _DATABASECHANGELOG_ where it fails.

Comment: Yep, but I think the check for existing `CONTEXT` and `LABEL` columns is within the `init()` method of [´StandardChangeLogHistoryService´](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java) class. I would assume that this is ran before any query to the `DATABASECHNAGELOG` table. But maybe you found a bug in liquibase? I don't have a test scenario here to reproduce this so I can't really tell...

Comment: As I understand the the Liquibase Code, the _init()_ is not called during _reportStatus()_. After running the _update_ command the two columns are added. But with the old version of Liquibase I get now checksum errors.

Comment: Checksums are created by using the fields `id/author/filepath`. Maybe your filepath changed? This can happen if you just put the files in a different directory. Why would want to use the old version anyway when you migrated to a new version?

Comment: Status and updateSQL do not change the database, which is why init() is not called. Liquibase 3.4.1 resolves the issue by using "SELECT *" instead of explicitly listing the columns which may not actually be there.